# Проблема с Selenium и chromewebdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, path

Возникла проблема с chromedriver.exe, требующийся для работы Selenium. Вроде разархивировал, добавил в патх, указал ссылку в коде, перезапустил комьютер, а всё равно выдаёт такую ошибку.

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1):

попробуй так:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\Users\\r.gorbunov\\IdeaProjects\\auto_test2\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```